# Apple Crash Report (2.3 and 8.1) app rejected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Crash Report by Apple review team, application is working perfectly for me and i have tested on various devices:

2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected
8.1 - Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights and the Apple Trademark List

2.1 Details

We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

```
Incident Identifier: A95029BB-2FEC-4B90-BBCF-AE4C543B7C86
CrashReporter Key:   a9230a18e9663c8318daa4bc0a3828077f1350c7
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             VAF [3157]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1B9A2B3C-9FD9-408D-94BB-736DE4C067A8/VAF.app/VAF
Identifier:          com.vaf
Version:             1 (1.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-05 11:07:36.36 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-03-05 11:07:34.34 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1848f5900 0x183f63f80 0x18ab80da0 0x10002c4bc 0x1852b8e2c 0x1848ad5f4 0x1848ad298 0x1848aa9ac 0x1847d9680 0x185ce8088 0x189650d90 0x10002c908 0x18437a8b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184498140 0x18447c000 + 115008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184560ef8 0x18455c000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184409dac 0x1843a8000 + 400812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183f3d3f4 0x183f3c000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183f59e98 0x183f3c000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183f64248 0x183f5c000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183f56f44 0x183f3c000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183f56b10 0x183f3c000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183f64120 0x183f5c000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001847d9728 0x1847d0000 + 38696
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000185ce8088 0x185cdc000 + 49288
11  UIKit                           0x0000000189650d90 0x1895d4000 + 511376
12  VAF                             0x000000010002c908 0x100028000 + 18696
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018437a8b8 0x184378000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001844994fc 0x18447c000 + 120060
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018435c94c 0x184348000 + 84300
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018434b7bc 0x184348000 + 14268

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184498b6c 0x18447c000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018455d530 0x18455c000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018455d020 0x18455c000 + 4128

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184498b6c 0x18447c000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018455d530 0x18455c000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018455d020 0x18455c000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184498b6c 0x18447c000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018455d530 0x18455c000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018455d020 0x18455c000 + 4128

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000013753c777
    x4: 0x0000000183f5ae02   x5: 0x000000016fdd7500   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x00000000ffffffff  x15: 0x00000000fffffffc
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a21e7000  x21: 0x000000016fdd7500  x22: 0x0000000137607ce0  x23: 0x00000001a21f2b68
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x92004471ced0a5a3  x26: 0x00000001376005d0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fdd7460   lr: 0x0000000184560ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fdd7440   pc: 0x0000000184498140 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100028000 - 0x10002ffff VAF arm64  <7962530132373cfc871a3000b35dc588> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1B9A2B3C-9FD9-408D-94BB-736DE4C067A8/VAF.app/VAF
0x12006c000 - 0x12009bfff dyld arm64  <9e98992ceed735e2ac4784cb28efe7c1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183ee4000 - 0x183ee5fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <c4cd04b37e5f34698856a9384aefff40> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x183ee8000 - 0x183f3bfff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <d430d0ad16893b76bbc52468f65d5906> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x183f3c000 - 0x183f5bfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <1c0a8ef87e8c37b2a577dc1a44e2b16e> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x183f5c000 - 0x1842c8fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <da8e482b3e7d3c40a798a0c86a3d6890> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1842cc000 - 0x1842d0fff libcache.dylib arm64  <242f50f854a1301fa6f76b4531101238> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1842d4000 - 0x1842dffff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <962b6da2f76d3b22afb83adeb2b030ef> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1842e0000 - 0x1842e3fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <516b8400a98f3a4fb8f82780faca4b31> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1842e4000 - 0x1842ebfff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <c027b29d770e3a5e83aa48463916d3ed> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1842ec000 - 0x184347fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <f3daba6e74753ddc9d7a3df953621d46> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x184348000 - 0x184376fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <aa5aa53cebb13e23a840ac24e4380c81> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x184378000 - 0x18437afff libdyld.dylib arm64  <217f387a9d803ad1b8543fbcae5c8ec0> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x18437c000 - 0x18437cfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <aec3e1f1241e33a888763b2b3d54fc16> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x184380000 - 0x184384fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <c0a027eb0fdf34c4948a7a579754bb94> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x184388000 - 0x184389fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <2fb2b791a3453c019640b22cee6a0c00> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18438c000 - 0x1843a2fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <c0b57534f20e3488a77be968b06665d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1843a4000 - 0x1843a5fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <294794ae7146331c8fd65a1ba652e7a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1843a8000 - 0x184427fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <880a61b1eb96367f9bd7af9ec768c89b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x184428000 - 0x18442bfff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <03109db3910b3d1db039296a8dcf3a6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x18442c000 - 0x18442efff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <fe2c6b6a57b6325887f02a3c867d36bf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x184430000 - 0x184431fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <4bfbf0b2029f31299048d8aa82f50cf4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x184434000 - 0x18444afff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <a920142634313a95ad276a8e7ce041fc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x18444c000 - 0x184454fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <aad8313dc34138e58674de8b37c8f823> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x184458000 - 0x184479fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <c38ce7aacdf33d4081b7a526c8c3034e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x18447c000 - 0x18449dfff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <13195140aba33e139925c949e4ec1e14> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1844a0000 - 0x1844bcfff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <784c81a596ec3863bbb18d2c6d57d1ce> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1844c0000 - 0x1844d9fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <d540cfed29133811b05483d34c1d1b12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1844dc000 - 0x18453bfff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <8668f3c7d2583a858e982e431ff0029b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x18453c000 - 0x184544fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <9294202d3e963025b416a89d70a0a9f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x184548000 - 0x184552fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <dd38cc9e177a31f1820c306f9a5cdb90> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x184554000 - 0x184559fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <7ad36a3f683830338c1023238ee36e2d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x18455c000 - 0x184564fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <699f755441ea3a8da43569da86269469> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x184568000 - 0x18456afff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <fe96a44b2ade3550a73fbec1d1766da4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x18456c000 - 0x18457cfff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <6168fd469cbd3f4494d9a17c2128acb1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x184580000 - 0x184585fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <667befcaf5f339fb885e77ce99512fca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x184588000 - 0x184588fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <0735d1ebbd123718a8f17eb113615d6d> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x18458c000 - 0x1845b1fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <b4614a68d1cb32a99ff638ddb1181ff4> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1845b4000 - 0x1847b9fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <5c1540546de5350ab314c1d4c8a46d1b> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1847bc000 - 0x1847cdfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <c46172ce833d398a8f1b54d22a4aaeaf> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1847d0000 - 0x184b48fff CoreFoundation arm64  <121118a9a44d3518b99f3ebfd8806f69> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x184b4c000 - 0x184b5cfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <bfee5e310ce439f0912635ac0bdbcaef> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x184b60000 - 0x184b60fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <913105a7ca583fed80e6b6329387bd34> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x184b64000 - 0x184bd4fff IOKit arm64  <3183206b8f683af29d373817ca5ce34d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x184bd8000 - 0x184bf7fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <c9c425b7cc243ecfbb96c6b98a6737f9> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x184bf8000 - 0x184ce2fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <83e0d7a7234a3d93b70b33c650cce1c5> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x184ce4000 - 0x184d51fff Security arm64  <74474ceb538f35bdac96f3a9b7c9c2fa> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x184d54000 - 0x184dadfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <ede85de1bd2830518ea2caac42bad651> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x184db0000 - 0x184e98fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <ac049ebda5c534d7a81fff7ff8924192> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x184e9c000 - 0x185128fff CFNetwork arm64  <479946ecd173383d803077b338576727> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18512c000 - 0x185139fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <736f0f9f7b003dcbb91351472cedfd49> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x18513c000 - 0x185155fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <6a0f886fe05d3250a030dd9256b14c08> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x185158000 - 0x185172fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <8315a6fa429b3bc58da2a8d1cd259d61> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x185174000 - 0x18519efff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <2558513a9240332998aa09cdbf49f3ec> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1851a0000 - 0x1851befff libextension.dylib arm64  <b59c905587a63c9da06bfc8594ad8ae8> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x1851c0000 - 0x1851c1fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <49ce8afa64a033328e76f25af85ff4c4> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1851c4000 - 0x185431fff Foundation arm64  <9c53ce054a5630c98001ecd8fd71080a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x185434000 - 0x1854dffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <c534306ddf9e3b90b25e1b66695b0dd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1854e0000 - 0x185845fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <ca2b7c7ec1bb30b98c037998b26e01f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x185848000 - 0x185aa4fff vImage arm64  <a3390b9bac5135369964865d050a9b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x185aa8000 - 0x185acafff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <1dee62445ded325a93cfca54303bd378> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x185acc000 - 0x185ae0fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <0623251016ad33349829e232f4624c7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x185ae4000 - 0x185af3fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <5d1851c74bd63cb1a1b6e4dfe8dc59cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x185af4000 - 0x185b60fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <7a83ca773be63bbbb33a8e8d1c2da9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x185b64000 - 0x185b64fff vecLib arm64  <9008c7ee8a703d6faa091456a8990715> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x185b68000 - 0x185b68fff Accelerate arm64  <234dafe4fb09333a8bd23b74dff5670e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x185b6c000 - 0x185cd9fff CoreGraphics arm64  <b225beb40caf3521ad8af13986c9e25e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x185cdc000 - 0x185cf0fff GraphicsServices arm64  <9c0d8d96ee9a3abaa9ca2c1c83291ccd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x185cf4000 - 0x185d3cfff AppSupport arm64  <02b59c1c8da334a9852a3aa9bab98c07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x185d40000 - 0x185e01fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <afb0867c27e237b08d6fb64e1c44db59> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x185e04000 - 0x185e4cfff BaseBoard arm64  <c5af56c0a45f3308932ffa68e609ccd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x185e50000 - 0x185e5bfff AssertionServices arm64  <6be337b9a4ad3c72b1a9f5e48ac329db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x185e5c000 - 0x185e7dfff BackBoardServices arm64  <1098f9a35be63f4798089c25d613565c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x185e80000 - 0x185e83fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <7eb26bea09f53c1c9e8d732f9f8ba026> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x185e84000 - 0x185eb9fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <c1c5ada9ceb03917892e043fee80857f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x185ebc000 - 0x185ec6fff UserNotificationServices arm64  <e8dcb070485f38b699ef6b5decf244d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x185ec8000 - 0x185eedfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <eda15d90c5b4335299934d2c5fbcbede> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x185ef0000 - 0x185efffff MobileKeyBag arm64  <ed676cb30f5b38c8a4b00b84e66f216d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x185f00000 - 0x185f06fff IOSurface arm64  <5cb861f068073646a7e4f594baeb3dac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x185f08000 - 0x185f14fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <80c801d17a24305a9f55a53ba66d1e1a> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x185f18000 - 0x185f27fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <c01e9de574133fdf90a9526fc10457be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x185f28000 - 0x185f2afff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <799c7fc9ad973988a2d974d16a1a8618> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x185f2c000 - 0x185f6dfff AppleJPEG arm64  <244899ffb13030d09097bcb67d1c0f0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x185f70000 - 0x186291fff ImageIO arm64  <1dcba4911a183ca38528d0b4db7338a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x186294000 - 0x186298fff TCC arm64  <785cd2d136fd3300a63f0c9b65a69b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x18629c000 - 0x1862a1fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <df37471257ac3732924711a6cc7aba99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1862a4000 - 0x1862b1fff PowerLog arm64  <af9c5f3d9b3e3a02ab7c00bf83a3b0c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1862b4000 - 0x186311fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <ec797d85e16f343a9b5d39ee63204090> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x186314000 - 0x186326fff CommonUtilities arm64  <8f96b3d9ea333d20985ec6f5d77a5946> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x186328000 - 0x18633ffff libcompression.dylib arm64  <fecdce66a127392f968b6b0fe72b819c> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x186340000 - 0x18658afff CoreData arm64  <5d453eca9d25369fbe1152ec7aa44b1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x18658c000 - 0x186590fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <05aad56f45e13172ad7a5d9fc156ccd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x186594000 - 0x186598fff IOAccelerator arm64  <7889e7b1f9ad30f19539dacc3a4e1a48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x18659c000 - 0x18659dfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <a1731d84b8ec3cc78b140153b1f97694> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1865a0000 - 0x1865a3fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <f67161256ed732219f5599270648e012> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1865a4000 - 0x1865eafff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <d533fa1b7b5f3f1b9a38a8aa0d4b80c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1865ec000 - 0x1865f6fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <102edb9f54593c12b761398991a2878f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x1865f8000 - 0x1865fefff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <33cde30cbca83a60957157185c6fbe45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x186600000 - 0x186600fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <56af01754111343da708ce2963dc993c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x186604000 - 0x18664afff Metal arm64  <2c6f99dd5edb3b4b9bb8233c120dd370> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x18664c000 - 0x186656fff OpenGLES arm64  <cfb6dabfaa5c32bb84bfbb8c31fb2e06> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x186658000 - 0x186678fff CoreVideo arm64  <653d4a02c4443e79b9dedc88fec89b4d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x18667c000 - 0x18667efff OAuth arm64  <ea5d8026af173483918a09c303104746> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x186680000 - 0x1866b7fff Accounts arm64  <70308607c9873d7d827735c98303ef29> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1866b8000 - 0x1867aafff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <fadcb98c1c1b356c84f83a0405014023> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1867ac000 - 0x186868fff CoreAudio arm64  <7cc6066c806039bca940716231637628> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x18686c000 - 0x18686ffff UserFS arm64  <8e3c32ed612f310f8253a9fc3ef365f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x186870000 - 0x18695dfff CoreMedia arm64  <6ad8fea7e3033ea8ae61060f5e19f6b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x186960000 - 0x186968fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <86ae97c485ea3d27880d4075a0378a12> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x18696c000 - 0x1869defff CoreTelephony arm64  <9d5c070b5f1536399d8dc4583ef8240e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1869e0000 - 0x186ac0fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <fc643a21296736b5b2b61481d61a306e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x186ac4000 - 0x186b44fff VideoToolbox arm64  <be617809dd93333ab50db1e22fec1c11> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x186b48000 - 0x186b48fff FontServices arm64  <bbec62921db432008ff91dbecc9f5f63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x186b4c000 - 0x186c77fff CoreText arm64  <d116fec0cc2136cb9ccff9f0b77c0427> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x186c8c000 - 0x186cb3fff PersistentConnection arm64  <f891b056a74d3aecbc515a5dd93a182a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x186cb4000 - 0x186cbbfff DataMigration arm64  <4d957c76b4a535349f065e4e26e32a75> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x186cbc000 - 0x186fe2fff AudioToolbox arm64  <732b31e0907438e38393c1401a2326b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x186fe4000 - 0x187186fff QuartzCore arm64  <b18fd2d29c78340581fc516141c52a36> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x187188000 - 0x18718efff Netrb arm64  <89a82d19bfa832c3be2b4d8bcdaf04c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x187190000 - 0x1871a1fff libcmph.dylib arm64  <788e21990d61308cb3a8eeac6f28cda9> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x1871a4000 - 0x1871bffff libmis.dylib arm64  <75c4bd30d45838a7a276a4c687d9676c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x1871c0000 - 0x187241fff LanguageModeling arm64  <8f0afc836b7c31a4ba004f9ba495159c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x187244000 - 0x187304fff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <14f012126fcc31b985744406ffabdc4c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x187308000 - 0x18731ffff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <5a00674979ab31b1a216a56c1f60458e> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x187320000 - 0x1873e7fff ProofReader arm64  <1128b6d743133c6b80b762645c0a9e54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x1873e8000 - 0x1873eefff MediaAccessibility arm64  <1ad85ca5a76f3e6692df4fbb1b7d1019> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x1873f0000 - 0x1873fffff MobileAsset arm64  <10c161389d7039a0a01a8a338f349fae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x187400000 - 0x187458fff ColorSync arm64  <9e5c88dec3743290b78e9df8ec74492c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18745c000 - 0x1874a7fff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <5b5f3ef3b3503289aad9b60b08268721> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x1874a8000 - 0x1878d4fff FaceCore arm64  <c081228025fe3e6bb800430051181fb4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x1878d8000 - 0x187953fff Quagga arm64  <668639b359dd35b99fd432f187422807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x187954000 - 0x187af6fff CoreImage arm64  <b9d5db7c62583ce5aa67a929c32ecbdd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x187af8000 - 0x187b29fff TextInput arm64  <99990781f4e23fa4a7603033c12e7880> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x187b2c000 - 0x187b36fff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <925fa2dd49eb3ae9b2457f3bb3a56dc9> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x187b44000 - 0x188128fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <8734a54ac2923d9b9957c1a4b2cbc9eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x188314000 - 0x1892bbfff WebCore arm64  <31d224ffb1b03ef3aef621656fa6eb83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x1892bc000 - 0x1892e5fff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <e6a0f1496d6d33a2b64339fa29c76daa> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x1892e8000 - 0x1893c5fff WebKitLegacy arm64  <c3ad1cf573fc37f79202166b2a8e4de2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x1893c8000 - 0x18947ffff CoreUI arm64  <29d544d0b53e394aabcfc44fa72488ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x189480000 - 0x1894a5fff DictionaryServices arm64  <f39018d31eeb3d35b820df074d18f54b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x1894a8000 - 0x1894a8fff HangTracer arm64  <231afe8a1d2e31339c291c80e7c00bb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x1894ac000 - 0x1894fafff PhysicsKit arm64  <9ba1d2dbac4d34b2a984036875c03449> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x1894fc000 - 0x1895d2fff UIFoundation arm64  <9f36816edf3139ecbced1102ad25421f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x1895d4000 - 0x18a1ccfff UIKit arm64  <1ed8c851528d340980eaf65410c76c18> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18a21c000 - 0x18a235fff NetworkStatistics arm64  <e09050a83e2c34eb9fcaa4b53c8a0173> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x18a2b4000 - 0x18a3befff CoreMotion arm64  <d3400d1bc1a731b982b98726473872d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x18a3d4000 - 0x18a3dbfff CoreAUC arm64  <d61137796acf39239063a10e7571d567> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x18a3dc000 - 0x18a7f5fff MediaToolbox arm64  <fcec681f386c32ffbf9cbf87c51dfcec> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x18a7f8000 - 0x18a977fff Celestial arm64  <76d04f7ae8bf319b91d4c7db0106a360> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18aa58000 - 0x18aa59fff BTLEAudioController arm64  <142ecb401dca36c0b2fe630969f4aea6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x18aa5c000 - 0x18aad4fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <f3034400d6e43f9a9464a67430e4eab9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x18aad8000 - 0x18ac52fff AVFoundation arm64  <0540460d4dae33caa1e7448265f8dbe5> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x18b1cc000 - 0x18b1d1fff ConstantClasses arm64  <0ff28778ae7835688d319a72fa16c64d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x19601c000 - 0x19601efff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <d305ba7bb90332e19ce29d9ed8a653a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x196214000 - 0x196232fff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <40a91f99969a37b4b6864eca954d3fc3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x197d1c000 - 0x197d27fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <13e8d2a87baf3235aac346f540dfd38f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
```

Comment: did you check running your app on ios 9 or later devices?

Comment: @PratikShah Yes i checked on simulator's + real devices

Comment: ok so you diidn't found any crash while testing? try to test again after removing the build file,derived data and cleaning the project

Comment: Try to symbolicate the crash log.

Comment: Did you test your app on release mode?

Comment: @PratikShah no crashes found...

Comment: Did you use the exact IPA you submitted (not run from Xcode)? Do you have the dSYM files from that build (should be in your archive) -- if so, Symbolicate the crash so you know what line of your app is crashing and you can then post that code.